# Extracting double value from String getting java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

I am using the following logic to extract double value from a String. It works fine on the first String but raise an Exception on second String. The raised Exception is  `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.

```
public class StringHandling {

   public String processString(String string)
   {
        Scanner st = new Scanner(string);
        while (!st.hasNextDouble())
        {
            st.next();
        }
        double value = st.nextDouble();
        return String.valueOf(value);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
        String first = "Hey, he is 70.3 miles away.";
        String second = "{\"Hey\", \"he\" \"is\": 1.0, \"miles\" away}";
        StringHandling sh = new StringHandling();
        System.out.println("First Value is "+sh.processString(first));
        System.out.println("Second Value is "+sh.processString(second));
   }
}
```

I just want to know why it is raising the Exception.

Comment: Did you step it through to see the elements of the second? You do not cover the path where the Input does not have one double at all ... I suspect "1.0," is not a valid double, but I'm not sure how the Scanner will handle that.

Comment: I did try. But the error still persists.

Comment: You may change it to any double value you like. it will extract from the first string but not in case of second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
"{\"Hey\", \"he\" \"is\": 1.0, \"miles\" away}"
```

The `next` method of class `Scanner` by default gives you the next input until a space is reached.

The `next` method would fetch it like that:

```
{"Hey",
"he"
"is":
1.0,
"miles"
away}
```

In that case, you have `1.0,` which is **not** a `double` (note the comma).

That's why you get a `NoSuchElementException`: you keep doing `st.next()`, but a `double` is never found, so the end of the string gets reached and the Scanner doesn't find other elements.

Comment: Thanks the comma is the reason for the exception. after i removed the comma (1.0,-1.0) it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex pattern instead of the scanner:

```
public String processString(String string) {
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+))");
   Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
   while(m.find()) {
       return m.group(1);
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: You are right @ToasteR. But the thing is i just wanted to know the reason behind this error. Anyways thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

By default, a `Scanner` splits on white space. So your second example finds `1.0,` as one of the inputs, which it doesn't recognise as a double.

Your code also assumes that you'll exit the while loop because you found a double. In this case, there is no value to read so you get an exception.

### Solution 1 — Change Delimiter

One option is to change the delimiter used by your `Scanner` object. Perhaps to something like this:

```
st.useDelimiter("[^\\w.]");
```

This will break your input into "words" containing any combination of alphanumeric characters, underscores and periods.

### Solution 2 — Regex

You can find this value with a regular expression. The example below looks for numbers that include a decimal point and at least one decimal place:

```
public static String findWithRegex(String string) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.group();
    } else {
        // do something more useful here
        return "none";
    }
}
```